# Java only outputting initialized values

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, netbeans, xhtml

My Java project is only giving me the initialized values instead of the values I need from an equation. I've tested this in a few different ways, and what I noticed was my output was only pulling from the initialized values of 0.00 instead of the post equation values.

Here are the initial values

```
public class LaptopOrders {

private int orderSize = 0;
private String subTotal = "0.00";
private String tax = "0.00";
private String total = "0.00";
```

here is where the equation happens,

```
public void orderDetails()
{
    orderSize = 0;
    double s = 0;
    double t = 0;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //statement and connections
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try
    {
        final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/HPLaptopWeb";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "team", "secret");
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        //Query to get subTotal
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE orderNum='" + orderNum + "'");

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

         while(resultSet.next())
         {
            s = (s + resultSet.getDouble(13));
            orderSize++;
         }

         subTotal = df.format(s);
         t = (s * .0625);
         tax = df.format(t);
         total = df.format(s + t);
    }

    catch (SQLException e)
    {      
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally  //close the statement and connection
    {

        try
        {
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the output I know the output has lower case "l"s and the class is uppercase, but It didn't pull any info if it didn't have a lower case "l".

```
             <f:facet name="footer">
                 <b><h:outputText value="Subtotal: $#{laptopOrders.subTotal}"/></b><br />
                 <b><h:outputText value="Tax: $#{laptopOrders.tax}"/></b><br />
                 <b><h:outputText value="Total: $#{laptopOrders.total}"/></b>             
             </f:facet>
```

Comment: When is the `orderDetails()` method invoked and how do you refresh the value holders in the facelet ?

Comment: The thing is I have it used exactly the same in the cart portion of the project. The facet is refreshed when the user searches for an order.

Comment: If I were debugging this, I'd try changing the class name to `laptopOrders` with a lowercase l and see what happens. You don't have a variable called `laptopOrders` somewhere?